# How to adapt MongoDB query from Node.js driver format to Mongoose format

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I would appreciate some help with the syntax for a query using Mongoose.

I have this query which runs well using the MongoDB Node.js driver to remove an ObjectId from a nested array of Object IDs:

```
    let filter = { _id : new ObjectId('5f30b40839aab119f4b3e21d'), 'groups._id': new ObjectId('5f3a23ec3680923d04ff970c') };
    let update = { $pull: { "groups.$.students": new ObjectId('5f1a57a9d433f86ec0750c2c') }};

          client.db('database').collection('collection').findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, function(err, res) {
              if (err) console.log(err);
              console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
              client.close();
          });
```

When I try to run the query using Mongoose Schema, the query does not remove the ObjectId from the array, but it does not throw any errors:

```
let groupFilter = { _id: existingClassroom._id, 'groups._id': groupId };
let groupUpdate = { $pull: { "groups.$.students": existingUser._id } };
await Classroom.findOneAndUpdate(groupFilter, groupUpdate, {new: true}, async (err, doc) => {
 if(err){
  console.log(err);
 }
});
```

The Mongoose schema has the schema for these fields defined like this:

```
  groups:[
    {
      students:[
        mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
      ],
      dateCreated: {
          type: Date,
          default: Date.now
      }
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert string id to object id using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`,

```
let groupFilter = { 
  _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(existingClassroom._id), 
  'groups._id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(groupId) 
};
let groupUpdate = { 
  $pull: { 
    "groups.$.students": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(existingUser._id) 
  } 
};
await Classroom.findOneAndUpdate(groupFilter, groupUpdate, { new: true }, 
  async (err, doc) => { if (err) { console.log(err); } }
);
```